# How do I place a figure in class "article"

Tags: floats, positioning

I use the `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` to write a CV. I am trying to insert a portrait but the position is always not correct. I use the following `minipage` to do that:

```
\begin{minipage}[r]{0.48\textwidth}
\vskip -0.5in
%\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, height=0.15\textheight]{Picture1.jpg}
\end{minipage}
```

However, the position is not going to where I want it to be. I already circle the position I want. [image]

Comment: Have you checked that there actually is `0.48\textwidth` of unused space to play with? (Aside: it doesn't look like it from the screenshot you posted.) If there isn't enough space left on the current line, LaTeX will issue a warning message about an overfull line and insert a line break before placing the `minipage`. A general comment: the `minipage` environment knows about 3 positioning specifiers: t, c, and b (for top, center, and bottom); it won't do anything with `r`. You might start with `\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}` and see if that works; if it does, keep increasing the width slowly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it did not work.

Comment: Sorry, but comments such as "it did not work" are not actionable and not productive. So far, you've let on that you employ the `article` document class and that you run some fragment of LaTeX code; however, you have said nothing about what comes before or afterward that fragment. Now you say that you tried my suggestion but that "it did not work". Could you maybe provide just a bit more information? E.g., do you receive an error message or a warning message? Unless you start providing some usable information, chances that anyone will be able to guess what's going on are rather slim.

Comment: You should move your `minipage` to the right. For example by `\hfill`: `\hfill\begin{minipage}[r]{0.48\textwidth}
\vskip -0.5in \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth,height=0.15\textheight]{Picture1.jpg}
\end{minipage}`. But for better advise you should provide MWE, which reproduce your problem.

Comment: `\begin{minipage}[r]{` minipage does not have an `r` option this will be ignored without warning, but you do not need minipage here you can just `\includegraphics` directly (use `\raisebox` to raise or lower it)

Comment: You might also want to look at \raisebox, \smash, \rlap and \llap.  You can also use \makebox[\textwidth][r]{...} to move to the right edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{l}m{#1}}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{ L{10cm}  C{3cm} }
        text &\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]